# How to change the line "var domToPdf = require('dom-to-pdf');"

Tags: node.js, browserify

I want to use a NodeJs Module on the browser. I read, that I can do this with http://browserify.org/.
Concret I want to use this NodeJs Module: https://github.com/ovvn/dom-to-pdf
So I create a bundle.js form this like explained here: http://browserify.org/

You can see my bundle in my github repo: https://github.com/astridx/dom-to-pdf/blob/javascriptexport_browserify/bundle.js

But now I do not know how to go on. I created an example: https://github.com/astridx/dom-to-pdf/blob/javascriptexport_browserify/example/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="./../bundle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test">TODO write content</div>
        <script>
            var domToPdf = require('dom-to-pdf');
            var element = document.getElementById('test');
            var options = {
                filename: 'test.pdf'
            };
            domToPdf(element, options, function () {
                console.log('done');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But I do not know how to change the line `var domToPdf = require('dom-to-pdf');`

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `import` instead, but you might need babel for that to work properly.

e.g `import domToPdf from 'dom-to-pdf'`;

Comment: Did you mean?  babel -> to label ?